# Displaying scores in tutorial projects - GUI and UI

Tags: unity, gui

I've just started learning to use unity by working through the tutorial projects but in both roll-a-ball and space shooter I've hit dead ends in the text lessons. The lessons tell you to simply add a GUI text object but they don't seen to exist anymore. From what I've gathered they have been replaced with UI text, but I can't find any documentation that explains how to use them in the way the tutorial describes.

Essentially my question is "how do I complete lesson 15 of the space shooter tutorial project now that unity doesn't let me create GUI text objects in the hierarchy?" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Component / Rendering GUIText ;)

Comment: If you would like a great video that incorporates the new UI check this one out in the unity live training.  http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/panels-panes-windows

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is now the old-way to do GUI stuff. The new UI system that came with Unity 4.6 is, I think, extremely robust and easier to learn and work with. I strongly recommend you go through the new UI tutorials on [Unity's new UI tutorials page](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-canvas) and try to make your UI look like what it is seen on the tutorial you are working on by using the new UI system.

Here's [another tutorial series for a pause menu from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-scQ-AZLMhA&list=PLVNVz3FV6VpJaGrR5tyqBJ-v4KyBjehPW&index=1) that helped me get my hands on new UI system. It might be useful for you once you start to work on your pause menu.